# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'modal_html'. Expected a ':'

Tags: javascript

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'modal_html'. Expected a ':'
following the property name 'var'. (anonymous function) — modal.self-

```
Helpers = window.Helpers || {}
Helpers.Bootstrap = Helpers.Bootstrap || {}

Helpers.Bootstrap.Modal = {

  var modal_html = `
  <div class="modal fade" id="AlertModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="AlertModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="AlertModalLabel">${title}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          ${message}
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          ${ button_html( button1 )}
          ${ button_html( button2 )}
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  `;

  init(title, message, button1, button2, existingelementid) {
    if (b === undefined) {
      Helpers.Bootstrap.Modal.closee(existingelementid)
    }
    modal_html
  }

  close(elementid) {
    $( elementid + " .close").click();
  }

  button_html(button_name) {
    var button_cancel = "<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>";
    var button_save   = "<button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary spinner" >Save</button>";
    var button_ok     = "<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Ok</button>";
    var button_close  = "<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>";

    switch(button_name) {
      case "cancel":
        button_cancel;
        break;
      case "save":
        button_save;
        break;
      case "ok":
        button_ok;
        break;
      case "close":
        button_close;
        break;
      default:
        button_name;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the line immediately before?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol please see the fiddle I added

Comment: You can't just put a `var` declaration in the middle of an object literal.

Comment: wrapped it in function but now get SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'init'. Expected '}' to end an object literal.. Do I make new question for this? https://jsfiddle.net/7mw4xfqu/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a lot of things wrong here:

- End your assignments `Helpers = window.Helpers || {}` and `Helpers.Bootstrap = Helpers.Bootstrap || {}` with semicolons `;` (just because!)
- I think `Helpers.Bootstrap.Modal.closee(existingelementid)` should be `.close` not `.closee`
- Your html in `modal_html` is missing a closing `</div>` tag in the end
- you cant decalare a `var` inside a object like you did with `var XXX = something;`
  insted you just do: `XXX : something,` <-- (note the `,` in the end)
- in your function `init` it just randomly says `modal_html` in the end (without assignment or anything else)
- the whole code in button_html is just utter gibberish...ofc `var button_cancel = "<button type="` is not a real assignment and continuing with 
  `button " class="` will just break everything!
  ---> YOU CAN'T USE `"` to delimiter inside of `""`
- You are never returning anything from your `switch`, (atleast thats what I think you want to do)
- there is alot more, but I suggest fixing this first, and maybe your original error will dissapear magically ;)

```js
Helpers = window.Helpers || {}; /* <------ */
Helpers.Bootstrap = Helpers.Bootstrap || {}; /* <------- */

Helpers.Bootstrap.Modal = {

  modal_html : `
  <div class="modal fade" id="AlertModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"               aria-labelledby="AlertModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="AlertModalLabel"></h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- <--------- -->
  `,


  
  
  button_html(button_name) {
  /*
    var button_cancel = "<button type="
    button " class="
    btn btn - outline - danger " data-dismiss="
    modal ">Cancel</button>";
    var button_save = "<button type="
    submit " class="
    btn btn - outline - primary spinner " >Save</button>";
    var button_ok = "<button type="
    button " class="
    btn btn - outline - primary " data-dismiss="
    modal ">Ok</button>";
    var button_close = "<button type="
    button " class="
    btn btn - outline - primary " data-dismiss="
    modal ">Close</button>";

    switch (button_name) {
      case "cancel":
        button_cancel;
        break;
      case "save":
        button_save;
        break;
      case "ok":
        button_ok;
        break;
      case "close":
        button_close;
        break;
      default:
        button_name;
    }
    
    THE ABOVE CODE IN THIS COMMENT IS ALL GIBBERISH AND IS NOT CORRECT */
  }

}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```